# Faster video processing in Python with GPU?

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, video-processing

I film lightning with my GoPro at 240fps for extended periods of time. I have created a Python program that use OpenCV to detect peaks of luminosity corresponding to lightning strikes and generate a brightness graph. Although it works fine, the processing speed is too slow. It takes 90s to process a 20s clip (on an i7 10700K).

I've benchmarked my code and found that just reading all the frames took 46s, processing 44s and printing 1s.

I didn't implement multi-threading because I don't think it would improve enough and I can just start processing multiple video on multiple terminal to get to 100% CPU usage.

Instead I'm looking for a way to do it on GPU, I can playback the video perfectly at 240fps so the processing (only adding all the pixel RGB value) should also be possible do to in 20s, probably less.

20s test clip (152Mo): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HMk5NGBbv8bWg4UtCwFv25I-WGAO00Cd/view?usp=sharing

[Expected graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHYb0.png)

The core of my code :

```py
while video.isOpened():
    success, frame = video.read()
    if success:
        index += 1
    else:
        if index >= length: break
        error += 1
        print('empty frame :', error)
        continue

    # Channel 0:B 1:G 2:R
    height, width, channels = frame.shape
    brightness.append(np.sum(frame[0:height, 0:width, 0:channel]))

    print(f'{index}/{length}')
video.release()
```

Also if you know a software that already does this faster I will take it, I'm only doing this in python because I didn't find anything.

Comment: You could try to downsample the video to 1x1px (or similarly small) using ffmpeg. Then Python should be able to decode and process it much faster, and the brightness peaks are still visible (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

You could use numba to run your code on the gpu:

```
from numba import jit, cuda

@jit(nopython=True, target_backend='cuda') # <-- If you have a cuda GPU
def process_video():
    while video.isOpened():
        success, frame = video.read()
        if success:
            index += 1
        else:
            if index >= length: break
            error += 1
            print('empty frame :', error)
            continue

        # Channel 0:B 1:G 2:R
        height, width, channels = frame.shape
        brightness.append(np.sum(frame[0:height, 0:width, 0:channel]))

        print(f'{index}/{length}')
    video.release()
```

If your goal is to detect peaks of luminosity it might be enough to process only a part of the video (processing the video at 60 fps for example). Then when you have found the start and end of the peak you could take that part of the video and only then use the 240fps.

EDIT:
numba has two modes: nopython and object mode. Nopython mode essentially compiles the function so it can run without the use of the python interpreter (which is faster). Object mode is more of a fallback for if nopython doesn't work, it will try to identify code it can compile, however when it can't it will use the python interpreter. When using the decorator you have to specify what you want to use. The recommended mode in the documentation (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html) is nopython. I have edited the code so that it will use the nopython mode.

Comment: Please provide a working example as I'm unable to make this work.

I get `NumbaDeprecationWarning with latest dependencies, as "nopython" argument is not supplied to numba.jit`
I've tried with nopython=False but it doesn't run on GPU then.

Comment: If I process at 60fps I miss 3/4 of the frames and a short lightning strike might only be visible for 1 or 2 frames.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a solution for your error. Those lighting strikes are faster then I thought, so my solution would not work. However Thomas posted a comment that proposes that you downsample the video, maybe that will work better.